# C# Regex: One or no occurrence of a string

Tags: c#, regex

Is there any better way to look for one or no occurrence of a string in C#? Right now, I am using the following statement for achieving the same.

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"[0-9]+([s][t][r][i][n][g])", "$1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: The regex appears to be checking for one or more digits followed by `string`, which is not what you state in the description. What exactly are you trying to match - please provide examples of inputs and expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`?` modifier tells you want exactly one or no occurences. SO, if I understood you right, you want something like

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"[0-9]+((?:string)?)", "$1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

`?:` before string stands for non-capturing group, so inner braces are not treated as a group and are not accessible with `.Groups` and `$<number>` expressions in replace

See repetition section. http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

Use string.contains method:

```
string s1 = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
string s2 = "fox"; 

if (s1.contains(s2))
{
Regex.Replace(input, @"[0-9]+([s][t][r][i][n][g])", "$1", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
}
```